# Load the contents of an iframe with python

Tags: python, html, iframe, beautifulsoup

I need to get the contents of an iframe using python.

As the web-page loads it submits a request and gets the content of the iframe in the response. When I use BeautifulSoup to get the data it just gives the initial blank iframe contents. Maybe the iframe has not loaded by that time I get the response.

Please help me to get the HTML contents of the iframe.

thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Do the initial request. Then get the source URL for the iframe and do another request to fetch the contents of the iframe. Just check if you need to pass any variables with the request.

Beautifulsoup doesn't execute any of the code that you are getting from a request. Depending on the complexity of the page, you may be able to emulate what happens when the page loads in a browser (like parsing a little of the javascript and using that info).

Ex.

```
<html>
    ...
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("iframeID").src = "http://addr.com/page.html" 
        });
    </script>
    ...
    <iframe id="iframeID"/>
    ...
</html>
```

Getting the source for the iframe in this case will be inconvenient, but possible. If the javascript does weird and wonderfull things, this gets harder. If the javascript is in a separate file, then you have to go and fetch that.

If things get too complex, look at another scraping solution (one where you run a whole javascript engine), I haven't used anything more complex myself.

Comment: Actually that frame has some hidden fields and as the html page loads that hidden fields get submitted to source url and get the response in the same iframe. I tried by targeting source url also.. but it provides the hidden fields,,, i want to get the content that appears after submitting those hidden form action(that includes hidden fields also).....

Comment: Update you question with the information. Maybe someone can help you if you clearly describe the problem?